# Generate an array within an array but only keep items

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying an experiment where I hard code some items of an array then splice in actual code to make a lot of items.

```
var data = [

    {'id':'1Q19'},
    d3.range(21).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_product', type:'td'} })
    
    ];
```

However, this is creating an array within an array, which I don't want.

### Question

Is there something I can simply chain on to my existing array/map generator line so that I can still use it for generating items in `data` but just keep the items it makes? I dont want another array in `data.`

Comment: Do you mean [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)?

Comment: spread operator `...`  ?   `data = [{},...d3.range(21).map..]`

Comment: @jabaa @cmgchess `.flat()` and `{},...` gave me multiple root error. Not sure I know what you mean, maybe a worked out example would get me there.

Comment: Try `data.flat()`. There are multiple examples in the links. There is also an example for `...`

Comment: didnt this work `var data = [{'id':'1Q19'},...d3.range(21).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_product',type:'td'} })];`

Comment: Ok, both work now, thanks. Data structures are like 4d chess to me